# parse XML attribute value using javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I get the first `url` value in the 'media:content'.

Here is my XML format

```
<root>
    <item>
        <title>title1</title>
        <media:group>
            <media:content url="http://delivery_sva/1kqoy0pabup891733zq15sm2t3.mp4" />
            <media:content url="http://delivery_sva/1kqoy0pabup891733zq15sm2t3.mp3" />
        </media:group>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>title2</title>
        <media:group>
            <media:content url="http://delivery_sva/1kqoy0pabup891733zq15sm2t3.mp4" />
            <media:content url="http://delivery_sva/1kqoy0pabup891733zq15sm2t3.mp3" />
        </media:group>
    </item>
</root>
```

I tried with the following code, but I am not able to getting the value of the attribute.

```
var doc = this.responseXML.documentElement;
var items = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
for (var c = 0; c < items.length; c++) {
    var item = items.item(c);
    var sTitle1 = item.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).text;
    var itemswebportal = item.getElementsByTagName("media:content");
    //currentwindow.sTitle1 is getting from the previous screen
    if (sTitle1 == currentwindow.sTitle1) {
        alert(itemswebportal[1].getAttribute("url"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What you get in the alert...??

Comment: i am getting blank response

Comment: </media:group> missing in your XML

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `:` in the `media:content`. Try escaping it with two `\`. But I recommend using jquery for simpler manipulation and consistency across browsers.

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4h9nq/1/).