# collection item() vs array []

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections

Apologies if this is a duplicate - it is not easy to search for.

I have today come across TWO questions using `someArrayOrCollection.item(i)` instead of my preferred `someArrayOrCollection[i]`

Example: [parse XML attribute value using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683863/parse-xml-attribute-value-using-javascript)

```
var sTitle1 = item.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0)....
```

where I would use

```
var sTitle1 = item.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]....
```

Last time I saw these where when only IE supported that notation.

My first instinct when I see .item() is to correct it to []. Should I or is it harmless or perhaps even best practice these days?

Interestingly almost all the collections at MDN mentions the [item](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList.item?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FNodeList.item) method but their examples use [] - for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: Were they actually using an array? Could they have been using a type of object that uses an `.item()` accessor and does not have a `[]` accessor?

Comment: Are you talking about `.item()` on a dom collection? That's not the same as just an array.  `Array.prototype` doesn't have an item function.

Comment: Since `.item()` only refers to collections (maybe not all of them), it's better to use `[i]` because it's supported by all. I'm guessing you were looking at an `HTMLCollection`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Comment: @Ian that is what I gathered. Please see update for the last example I had

Answer (score 4):

For [`NamedNodeMap`s](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-core.html#ID-1780488922) `[]` acts as a sugar for both `.item` and `.getNamedItem`, which makes it possible to build a contrived example where index will be different from `.item`:

```
<div id="x" 2e0="wtf" class="foo" ></div>

<script>
a = document.getElementById("x").attributes;
console.log(a["2e0"].nodeValue)         // wtf
console.log(a.item("2e0").nodeValue)    // foo
</script>
```

Needless to say, this is purely theoretical, in the real life `[]` is a safe choice.