# Javascript: retrieve hidden field value inside element with ID

Tags: javascript, html, input

guess I have this

```
<td id="c1s2a"><input type="hidden" name="allow_move" value="1"></td>
```

how can I access the element 'allow_move' referring with the id c1s2a?
there are many allow_move named inputs, so I can't use document.getElementsByName("allow_move").

I tried this: `document.getElementById("c1s2a").allow_move=0;` but it did not work.
*(Yes, I want to change its value)*

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12166811/1375372

Answer (score 4):

If you really have just the input tag inside the td (and no other text, whitespace, or tags), you can simply use the following to get a reference to that element:

```
document.getElementById("c1s2a").firstChild;
```

To set its value:

```
document.getElementById("c1s2a").firstChild.value = 0;
```

There is also a property called `firstElementChild`, which ignores text nodes and comment nodes, but unfortunately isn't supported in IE before version 9.

---

Another option on modern browsers is `document.querySelector`, that takes a CSS selector and returns a DOM node. The [support table](http://caniuse.com/#search=queryselector) says it's IE8+, but I heard there are some compatibility issues on IE8.

Examples:

```
document.querySelector("#c1s2a input").value = 0;
```

or

```
document.querySelector("#c1s2a input[name='allow_move']").value = 0;
```

Comment: This one here is the neatest

Comment: @Isaac Someone doesn't agree (I got -1)

Comment: Not in my opinion. inelegant and will break if the code is formatted in any way

Comment: `If you really have just the input tag inside the td` Which from what we can see is true. It still stands

Comment: I agree it may break, but how can this be less elegant than what you suggested? It looks a lot cleaner. @mplungjan

Comment: I prefer the getElement...getElements since it is the same type of access and will not break at a space

Comment: While your answer gets the job done and is cleaner, mplungjan's is more readable and allows for the element to be moved around in the future while not breaking (assuming no other elements by name "allow_move" are added).  I don't have to go to the HTML to determine which element is the first child.

Comment: @BLaZuRE Sure. I like it that we're presenting different options. I'm actually surprised that nobody said "use jquery" yet.

Comment: I have reverted my downvote since it seems there is no getElementsByName for a TD element

Comment: Funny I was about to look at querySelector but refrained due to incompatibility. jQuery would be safer then

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot rely on the input being the first child, try this:

```
document.getElementById("c1s2a").children["allow_move"]
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/KemmU/

Comment: This may be the easiest solution indeed.

Comment: [IE9 (IE6-8 include comment nodes)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.children)

Comment: @mplungjan Will comment nodes make a difference when using the element's name as a subscript? BTW, the answer to [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16684022/825789) seems to imply this should work.

Comment: [It still works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/KemmU/2/) even with comment nodes in the collection (or whatever that is).

Answer (score 2):

I would have sworn that

```
document.getElementById("c1s2a").getElementsByName("allow_move")[0].value=0
```

would work, but as [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/wHf32/) shows, it gives Uncaught typeerror for the cell.getElementsByName!!!

Here is an alternative that I am not too happy about

```
window.onload=function() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByName("allow_move");
    for (var i=0, n=inputs.length;i<n;i++) {
        console.log(inputs[i].parentNode.id)
        if (inputs[i].parentNode.id=="c1s2a") {
            inputs[i].value=0;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `getElementsByName`?

Comment: Turns out this doesn't work at all `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableCellElement> has no method 'getElementsByName' `

Comment: Yes I see that. That is really surprising

Comment: An alternative: `document.getElementsByName("allow_move")[x].value = 0;`, but you have to choose the correct element index.  `document.getElementById("c1s2a").childNodes.item(0).value = 0;` may also work.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this. Some more efficient than others.

```
var allow_moves = document.getElementsByName("allow_move");
var index=0;
for(var j=allow_moves.length; index<=j; index++)
{
    if(allow_moves[index]&&allow_moves[index].parentNode.id=='c1s2a')break;
}
if(index<allow_moves.length)console.log(allow_moves[index].value);


console.log(document.getElementById("c1s2a").firstElementChild.value);


console.log(document.getElementById("c1s2a").childNodes[1].value);


console.log(document.getElementById("c1s2a").children["allow_move"].value);


//because I like being difficult, and because you never should, here is the regex way
//get the value
console.log(document.getElementById("c1s2a").innerHTML.replace(/([\s\S]*value=\")([^"]*)([\s\S]*)/g,"$2"));
//replace the value
document.getElementById("c1s2a").innerHTML = document.getElementById("c1s2a").innerHTML.replace(/([\s\S]*value=\")([^"]*)([\s\S]*)/g,"$1"+newValue+"$3");
```